# returning a file to a client to display

Tags: c#, download, client, memorystream

On the server side, I have the following simple statement which includes the contents of the actual file in bytes (AttachmentFile).

```
MemoryStream stream = null;

stream = new MemoryStream(attachment.AttachmentFile);
```

All I want to do is to send the file to the client to open it up in a web browser. I've searched the web, but cannot seem to find the right solution.

Can someone please give me some code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a quite good article about transfering file with WCF:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Sadly I cannot add this message as a comment.